# Finding the memory position of a mapping

Tags: evm, storage, get-storage-at

I want to read data from an internal mapping variable using  `getStorageAt()`, but this requires knowledge of the index where that variable is stored in memory.

The documentation says:

```
Due to their unpredictable size, mapping and dynamically-sized array types 
use a Keccak-256 hash computation to find the starting position of the value 
or the array data. These starting positions are always full stack slots.

The mapping or the dynamic array itself occupies a slot in storage at some 
position p according to the above rule (or by recursively applying this rule 
for mappings of mappings or arrays of arrays).
```

But it does not give further detail on what computation is used to find `p`. Anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Hopefully https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/ will help.